# How can I create generic 2D arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, unity-game-engine, .net-2.0

I have a lot of different grids that contains Enums like this

```
enum PEDESTRIAN_STATE { CANNOT_WALK, CAN_WALK, SHOULD_WALK };
static PEDESTRIAN_STATE[,] grid;
```

and I have functions like this:

```
public static PEDESTRIAN_STATE Get(int x, int y)
{
    return grid[x, y];
}
```

Now, I have several different 2D arrays that contain different enums. How can I make these Generic so i can move this into a base class?

Comment: Are those arrays each in their own class or something? It would make way more sense to just make the `Get` method generic and pass in the array as an extra parameter.

Comment: Currently there is 4 subclasses, all with arrays containing different enum values. I would like to move them up into the baseclass. And this is a simplified explaination of the problem so it might make more sense to do so and so if you start thinking outside what i just asked, but I really just want to know how to do what I asked. (if possible)

Comment: `public abstract class Base<T> where T: struct { protected static T[,] grid }` should probably do the trick then. Note that there is no constraint specifically for enums so the best you can do is put a `struct` constraint and maybe test if `T` is an enum in the constructor.

Comment: Why are you using ALL CAPITALS?  It will cause problems.  It's very easy to google up the correct capitalisation for Unity.